# How do I control the automatic "email changed" notice?

Tags: contacts, email

I have been doing cleanup in our CiviCRM, like merging duplicates and fixing errors. I changed an email address for one contact that I (incorrectly) thought was wrong, but I immediately heard from the person to let us know that the original email was correct. He responded to an automated system email that looks like the text below. I had no idea that it would trigger this notice, and have not been able to find the setup for it anywhere. Where is the admin page that controls or edits these notices?
Civicrm 5.38.1 on Wordpress 5.7.2.

> Subject: [Site name] Email Changed
>
> Hi,
>
> This notice confirms that your email address on [site name] was changed to xxxxx@email.com.
>
> If you did not change your email, please contact the Site Administrator at
> webmaster@example.com
>
> This email has been sent to yyyyy@email.com
>
> Regards,

Comment: I think that's a wordpress thing not civi - there might be a setting or plugin on the wordpress side to turn it off.

Comment: Yes you are correct, it is from wp_update_user() in wp-includes/user.php. I never saw that before. Thanks!